# codeigniter get value after submit form

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have modal using form selection ajax with submit button

**modal code**

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row" id="modal-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="project-loa" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select Project</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select id="project-load-modal" class="form-control" name="proj_name" style="width: 100%">
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->              
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'C_MRCR_A/generate'; ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button></a>       
      </div>
```

my value selection option is fine

**controller**

```
public function generate(){
    $proj_name = $this->input->get('proj_name'); 
    echo $proj_name;
}
```

i want get value from my selection form using controller.
when the submit is click, i get nothing in my console. what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
//give id to submit button button_id
$("#button_id").on('click', function () {  
var proj_name = $("#project-load-modal").val();
    $.post(base_url + 'generator_url'+proj_name, function (response) {
        if (response.code == '1') {
           //message if you want to show
        } else {
           //message if you want to show
        }
    });
}
//make route
$route['generator_url/(:any)']='ControllerName/generate/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add action and method attribute to form element

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url().'C_MRCR_A/generate'; ?>" method="get">
```

Take submit button inside the form element.

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
</form>
```